# Nginx using regex to serve images from location and hash the path with md5

Tags: nginx

As of right now, I am serving images using the following regex inside nginx

```
server {
    server_name localhost;

    location ~* \/catalog(\/\d+)(\/\d+)(\/\d+.png|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg)$ {
        alias /catalog$1$2$3;
    }
}
```

This makes it work with a path like

> http://localhost/catalog/1/1/1.png

However for my idea I need to encrypt that path

> http://localhost/catalog/sdasd8ds78asda8/as7da8sd7a8sda/1.png

I have so far looked into the [Securing URLs with the Secure Link Module in NGINX and NGINX Plus](https://www.nginx.com/blog/securing-urls-secure-link-module-nginx-plus/) and [Securing files with Nginx](https://prathamsatam67.medium.com/securing-files-with-nginx-c15eed74b50f), these two sources and many more delivered me no results so far. Mainly because installing the secure link module when Nginx is already installed proves to be difficult and I have not managed to test with it properly.

If there is another way to hash with MD5 for paths, then I would like to know a solution to this problem.

Comment: md5 is a hashing algorithms not a encryption. Hashing is a one way thing. You cant decrypt md5. And why do  this obfuscation?

Comment: @Marc I have my reasons for trying to hash the path, don't need to share those reasons, just need a solution.

Comment: You never will get a solution. Hashing is one way, and not a encryption. Use something else than md5... hashing != encryption

Comment: I must correct my previous comment. I didnt tought about maps in nginx. You could create a map with hashes, and the mapped real path to it. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html But not in the case of "encryption"

Comment: @Marc doesn't really need to be encrypted, can be hashed as long as the original path isn't visible to other users

Comment: Then you could work with a mapped path from my previous comment. You just need to find a way to create the map, If i remember correctly its also possible to include a map as a txt file. You just need to create the mapping external/outside of nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Marc I found a way to use mapping in a way to mask the url while using regex.

```
map $xname $xid {
    "/abc" "/1";
    "/hoho" "/2";
}

map $yname $yid {
    "/abc" "/1";
    "/hoho" "/2";
}

server {
    server_name localhost;

    location ~* \/catalog(\/\w+)(\/\w+)(\/\d+.png|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg)$ {
        set $xname $1;
        set $yname $2;
        alias /catalog$xid$yid$3;
    }
}
```

By making use of regex and the set feature for the ngx_http_map_module I was able to mask the url on two different sections.